# Не могу сделать перегрузку C++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* StrCat(char* str1, char* str2);

class String
{
public:
    String(int);
    String(const String&);

    void showArray();
    void operator +(char *s) //что должен выполнить оператор +
    {
        StrCat(*str, s); //сложение строк
    }
    char* &operator[](int j);

    ~String();

private:
    char **str;
    int sizeOfArray;
};

String::String(int size)
{
    sizeOfArray = size;
    str = new char *[sizeOfArray];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        str[i] = new char[2048];
    }
}

String::String(const String& obj)
{
    sizeOfArray = obj.sizeOfArray;
    str = new char *[sizeOfArray];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        str[i] = new char[2048];
        str[i] = obj.str[i];

    }
}

char* &String::operator[](int j)
{
    if (sizeOfArray <= j)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    return str[j];
}

void String::showArray()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        cout << str[i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

String::~String()
{
    delete str;
}

int StrLen(char* _str)
{
    int size = 0;

    for (; _str[size] != 0; size++);

    return size;
}

void StrCpy(char* in_str, char* src_str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < StrLen(in_str); i++)
        in_str[i] = src_str[i];
}

char* StrCat(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    int sz = StrLen(str1) + StrLen(str2);

    char* ts = new char[sz + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < StrLen(str1); i++)
        ts[i] = str1[i];
    for (int ii = StrLen(str1), j = 0; ii <= sz; ii++, j++)
        ts[ii] = str2[j];

    delete str1;
    str1 = ts;

    return str1;
}

int main()
{
    String a(3);
    String b(6);
    a[0] = "1";
    a[1] = "2";
    a[2] = "3";
    a[0] + a[1];
    cout << a[0];
    system("pause");
}
```

Не понимаю ошибку(((, надо сделать a[0] + a[2] - например, и чтобы в a[0] добавилась строка a[2];

Comment: При выделении памяти для массива, т.е. `new[]` c квадратными скобками, освобождать надо тоже с квадратными скобками: `delete []`.

Answer (score 3):

Ваша `StrCat(char* str1, char* str2)` сначала принимает указатели по значению, а затем делает с ними это:

```
str1 = ts;
```

«По значению» означает, что `str1` — это всего лишь *копия* того `*str`, который вы передали функции при вызове. Вам же нужна передача по ссылке. Измените объявление функции на:

```
 void StrCat(char*& str1, char* str2)
```

Только после этого любая модификация `str1` будет отражаться на `*str`.

---

***P. S.:*** По хорошему, бинарные операторы (включая `+`) не должны трогать свои параметры, а возвращать вместо этого новое значение. Вам по смыслу нужен модифицирующий оператор `+=`:

```
a[0] += a[1];
```

*Его объявление практически ничем не отличается от такового для обычного плюса:*

```
class String
{
public:
    void operator +=(const char *s)
    {
        StrCat(*str, s);
        return *this;
    }

    // ...
};
```

*Обратите внимание, что я защитил данные по указателю `s` от случайного изменения, сделав этот указатель константным.*

Comment: String operator +(char *s)
 {
  StrCat(*str, s);
  return *this;
 }
вижла сказала так изменить, но теперь все равно ошибки

Comment: @Артем, ошибка была не в этом. Вы добавили амперсанд к `str1` в объявлении `StrCat`, как я написал?

Comment: да. И мне вижла сказала void заменить на String

Comment: @Артем, потому что `По хорошему, бинарные операторы (включая +) не должны трогать свои параметры, а возвращать вместо этого новое значение`. Студия «докопалась» до второй части предложения. На ваше счастье она ещё не потребовала навесить константность на параметры (для соблюдения ещё и первой части предложения), после чего код бы даже не скомпилировался.

Comment: я все изменил как было выше сказано,но все равно ошибки

Comment: @Артем, расчехлил компилятор. У вас фундаментальная ошибка. В строке `a[0] + a[1]` оба операнда имеют тип `char*`. Соответственно, метод `operator+` вашего класса не вызывается вовсе, так как для этого левый операнд должен иметь тип `String`, или ссылки на него.

Comment: я не знаю как это исправить, можете помочь ( а именно, вставить код)?

Comment: @Артем, сейчас почти час ночи, пошёл спать. Завтра на свежую голову подумаю над решением этой проблемы. Но навскидку могу предложить, чтобы `operator[]` возвращал не указатель на `char`, а объект класса-обёртки, в котором приватно хранится `char*`-указатель на строку и публично объявлены методы `operator+` (поскольку мы будем складывать не `char*` с `char*`-ом, а обёртку с `char`-ом) и `operator char*`, чтобы через неявное преобразование можно было вытаскивать этот указатель на строку.

Comment: @Артем, довёл код до ума, рабочего состояния и снабдил все изменения комментариями: https://gist.github.com/arhad/b3f13592922587335899acb14795d9bb

Comment: огромное спасибо